# Unable to resolve service for type for generic class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, fluentvalidation

I am using **FluentValidation** and I have created a generic class like so:

```
public class GenericValidator<T>: AbstractValidator<T>
{
    protected override bool PreValidate(ValidationContext<T> context, ValidationResult result)
    {
        if (context.InstanceToValidate != null) return true;

        result.Errors.Add(new ValidationFailure("model", Resources.NullModelError));

        return false;
    }
}
```

When I tried to use my application, it returned this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Api.Controllers.Strategies.StrategyValidator' while attempting to activate 'Api.Controllers.Strategies.Handlers.StrategySaveHandler'.

My `StrategyValidator` looks like this:

```
public class StrategyValidator : GenericValidator<StrategyViewModel>
{
    public StrategyValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(model => model.Url).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

I have a few of these for different entities and I would like to register them all.
I have tried a few ways:

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(GenericValidator<>));

services.AddSingleton(typeof(GenericValidator<>), typeof(GenericValidator<>));

services.AddSingleton(typeof(AbstractValidator<>));

services.AddSingleton(typeof(GenericValidator<>), typeof(AbstractValidator<>));
```

None of them worked.
Does anyone know what I can do to register all my validators rather than registering them one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided what the service requiring the DI looks like but you could 
register your validators manually like so: `services.AddSingleton(typeof(StrategyValidator))`

Additionally you may just want to leverage the generic forms in your services e.g instead of requesting a `StrategyValidator` you should request a  `GenericValidator<StrategyViewModel>`

But generally, Fluent provides an easy way of doing this using their extension methods

e.g

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(authorizationPolicy));
}).AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>())
```

**Note:** this will register all of the fluent validators that are within the same assembly as Startup.

Comment: RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining is slow I believe and scans the entire assembly. and services.AddSingleton(typeof(StrategyValidator)) wont work since it has a base class. it will complain that base class is not registered. Problem is to register baseclass. how to do this?

Comment: Slowness shouldnt matter its a one time registration cost.  Not sure what issue you're having you should probably create a new question

Comment: his problem was to register GenericValidator which is possibly and "abstract" class, DI doesnt like to register abstract classes. Solution is to remove "abstract" keyword and it works fine.